# Is there a way to make a java file useless in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a package and 2 java files inside the package. Now what I want is to make the files useless. They will be there in the package as the content inside is something which I do not want to lose but the files cannot be imported or run . It is something similar to how we can close a project in eclipse. Is there any way?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to access the files contents at runtime, but they are not Java source files?

Comment: I do not want to run/use them, just keep them there invisible to the IDE. But sometimes if i want i can see the code written there for my reference.

Comment: Put them somewhere else, like github. Your packages should not be a storage place for reference material.

Comment: You could put them in a folder which is not part of the "source path"

Comment: "useless" is a very ambiguous description in programming. Please be more specific. Why are those files in the package if you don't want to use them? Consider that it may not be the right place for them.

Comment: In _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Sources_ you can exclude files or folders. But better move the Java file out of the source folder, into a documentation folder. If it is something that is (currently) not needed, rely on your version control (e.g. Git) and delete it.